# The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page

Tags: html, google-chrome, audiocontext

I'm using the jspsych.js module, and when using it, I look at the console and I'm getting this error:
The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

and it takes me to this lines of code:

```
 core.webaudio_context = (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.AudioContext !== 'undefined') ? new AudioContext() : null;
```

I don't get where the mistake is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to a user-events to initiate audio.

Can you check the error lines again? Probably you are trying to start audio automatically but it's not possible.

add button your page:

```
<button class="play">Play</button>
```

Then add function to use your audio source the following;

```
play.onclick = function() {
audioSource.start(0);
//or another function to use audio source
}
```

Comment: The question was about jsPsych.js but the answer is still valid. Have a "html-button-response" prior to playing sounds (or even prior to preload-ing them), and things will work nicely.